# modify message using set of rules in java

Tags: java

I have a message, for example `KU7`.
Also, I have a set of rules, like this:

```
Q K S 7 J ... U 
R Y L B 8 ... W
```

and so on. I need to translate the message using this rules. There is ~20. Translated message will be `YWB`.

**What I have tried:**

To create a method that takes a `char` as and argument, method has a lot of `case blocks` (all rules) and returns translated `char`. Then using `for loop` I loop through the message and translate symbol by symbol.
But I think it is not good solution.

Can anybody provide me with other ideas / solutions / links to similar questions?

Comment: Can you explain the way the rules work?

Comment: oh, yes. I forgot to explain)))

Comment: Do the rules have any associated priority/order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HashMap` for storing keys and corresponding entries.

```
HashMap<String,String> map = HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("Q","R");
...

String input  = "KU7";
String result = "";

for(char c : input.toCharArray())
    result += map.get(c+"");
```

Comment: It's better to use `StringBuilder` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> But I think it is not good solution.

Yes this is not a good idea to have `20 different` cases.

> Can anybody provide me with other ideas / solutions / links to similar
>   questions?

The ideal solution for your requirement, is to create a `HashMap<String, String>`, which contains all the rules. And use it to convert your string.

So, your Map will contains mappings in the form of `key-value` pair like this: -

```
{"Q":"R", "K":"Y", ...}
```

And to get value for a particular key, you can use: -

```
map.get("Q");
```